# Simple to learn .NET data provider?

Tags: database, c#, .net

I am new with .NET technologies (but rather familiar with other frameworks) and wanted to know what data provider is simple to learn.

Requirements:

- Simple to learn for .NET beginners
- Reasonably functional
- Supports a large number of relational databases

Comment: Can you narrow this down by explaining what databases you expect the provider to need to work with? Ideally, also explain more about what you're likely to find simple to learn: what's your background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean a ORM since a data provider is just a minimal layer between your app and the actual database, and should be changed without modifying your app.

- Entity Framework; this is the obvious choice because its provided by Microsoft. There is a lot of documentation out there, and if you just want to learn entity framework you can quickly do so by utilizing [LINQPad with EF](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx).
- [SqlFu](https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu); This is simpler, therefore easier to learn. Its also easy use sql for querying which should be familiar if you've earlier programming experience.
- MicroLite; Because someone said its the [easiest ORM to set up with different data providers](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/the-sorry-state-of-.net-orms.html), which maybe is the most relevant to your question.